# Present perfect simple

Tags: present-perfect

" I've died every day waiting for you "
The word everyday considered as unfinished Time period ?
I mean we could use it with present pefrect ?

Comment: You might have considered ***cried*** for your example, since logically it's not possible to die repeatedly. But as regards using present perfect - that's fine, *provided* that past state is directly relevant to "time of speaking" (even if it's only relevant because you're contrasting that past unhappiness with present joy).

Comment: [I mean ***could we*** use it with the pp?]

Answer (score 1):

- I've gone there every week and still have not met him. [the week is not over]
- I've died every day waiting for you. [the day is not over]

Spoken in a present time, the **time periods week and day have still not ended when the sentences are uttered.**

Compare the present perfect to the present, used to express a generality:

I go there every week and still have not met him.

I die every day waiting for you.

To emphasize the repeated nature of the situation in the past and present, the present perfect is used.

Answer (score 0):

You might have considered cried for your example, since logically it's not possible to die repeatedly. But as regards using present perfect - that's fine, provided that past state is directly relevant to "time of speaking" (even if it's only relevant because you're contrasting that past unhappiness with present joy).